# Excel VB Database connection test

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with a bit of VB code that copies the data across to a access database.  This copies the data from one sheet to a cache sheet and then from the cache sheet to the db using a flag to identify new data,  This works ok but we would like to add a connection test to check if the connection to the database is ok.

This is the code i have below for the connection test:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim canConnect As Boolean
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
  "Data Source=\\G-FILE1\Common_Files\All Users\Robert T\Cash Sheets\CashSheets.mdb;"
If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then
canConnect = True
cnn.Close
MsgBox "Connection UP", vbOKOnly
Else
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
    "Data Source=\\G-FILE1\Common_File\All Users\Robert T\Cash Sheets\CashSheets.mdb;"
cnn.Close
If cnn.State = adStateClosed Then
canConnect = False
cnn.Close
MsgBox "Connection DOWN!", vbOKOnly

End If
End If
```

So what I want to do is this:

When button clicked > data is sent to cache sheet (Working) > Test DB connection > If not available, then msgbox user informing them > carry on caching sheet

I dont want the error window to appear, rather a msgbox and let the rest of the code carry on..

Hope this edit is a bit clearer..

Regards

Comment: Could you clarify what your problem is? This is more of a "I get this error and I can't understand why" area.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough if the file is available:

```
If Dir(accessFilePath) = "" Then
  'file not found!
else
  'file found!
end if
```